# How I can implement *asdict() or *asdict() using @dataclass

Tags: python, python-dataclasses

I can't implement asdisct. I have read information but I still have errors when using asdict.

```
@dataclass
class InfoMessage():
    """Информационное сообщение o тренировке."""
    def __init__(self,
                 training_type: str,  # Тип тренировки.
                 duration: float,  # Продолжительность тренировки.
                 distance: float,  # Продолжительность тренировки.
                 speed: float,  # Дистанция, выполняемая на тренировке.
                 calories: float) -> None:  # Калории, сжигаемые на тренировке.
        self.training_type = training_type    # имя класса тренировки.
        self.duration = duration    # длительность тренировки в часах.
        # дистанция в километрах, которую преодолел пользователь
        # за время тренировки.
        self.distance = distance
        # средняя скорость, с которой двигался пользователь.
        self.speed = speed
        # количество килокалорий, которое израсходовал пользователь
        # за время тренировки.
        self.calories = calories
        self.message = ('Тип тренировки: {self.training_type}_1d;'
                        'Длительность: {self.duration:.3f}_1d ч.; '
                        'Дистанция: {self.distance:.3f}_1d км; '
                        'Ср. скорость: {self.speed:.3f}_1d км/ч; '
                        'Потрачено ккал: {self.calories:.3f}_1d.')

    def get_message(self) -> str:
        """функция для отображения окончательного сообщения."""
        return self.message.format(*asdict(self))
```

Comment: You just wrote a regular class and slapped `@dataclass` on it. That's not how `@dataclass` works. You need to go read the dataclasses documentation.

Comment: This is mistake: (venv) PS C:\Dev\hw_python_oop> & c:/Dev/hw_python_oop/venv/Scripts/python.exe c:/Dev/hw_python_oop/homework.py
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "c:\Dev\hw_python_oop\homework.py", line 228, in <module>
    main(training)
  File "c:\Dev\hw_python_oop\homework.py", line 212, in main
    info_print = InfoMessage.get_message(info)
  File "c:\Dev\hw_python_oop\homework.py", line 62, in get_message
    return self.message.format(*asdict(self))
KeyError: 'self'
(venv) PS C:\Dev\hw_python_oop>

Comment: `dict((field.name, getattr(self, field.name)) for field in fields(self))`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I don't think you  are making use of the `@dataclass` decorator here, but you also don't need to to fix your problem. If you pass self to your string template it should format nicely.

```py
    def get_message(self) -> str:
        return self.message.format(self=self)
```

However, I think you are on the right track with a `dataclass` as this could make your code a lot simpler:

```py
@dataclass
class InfoMessage:
    training_type: str  
    duration: float 
    distance: float 
    speed: float
    calories: float
    
    _MESSAGE_TEMPLATE = (
        'Тип тренировки: {self.training_type}_1d;'
        'Длительность: {self.duration:.3f}_1d ч.; '
        'Дистанция: {self.distance:.3f}_1d км; '
        'Ср. скорость: {self.speed:.3f}_1d км/ч; '
        'Потрачено ккал: {self.calories:.3f}_1d.'
    )
        
    def get_message(self) -> str:
        return self._MESSAGE_TEMPLATE.format(self=self)
```

If you only use this for debugging purposes, then you might find the natural stringification from `dataclass` is good enough:

```py
print(InfoMessage(training_type="training type", duration=1, distance=2, speed=3.0, calories=4.0))

# InfoMessage(training_type='training type', duration=1, distance=2, speed=3.0, calories=4.0)
```

Comment: Thanks @Jon Betts. In this example (code) How can I implement asdict? I read information about that but I dont get it.

Comment: Don't use `{self.`} in your template and pass in the values raw `.format(**asdict(self))`, but I'm not sure why you would as it would just be slower?